# Nodejs api load data based on query string value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As a beginner, I am building a simple site using MEAN stack technologies. I have an api that gets quiz data object based on oject _id. All working fine. What I am trying to do is, based on the query string value from my url `http://localhost:3000/viewQuiz?gpQ=59b2ac3cfc2283480879025c` I want the api to load data rather than hard coding like I have shown below. What different I'm doing here is I have a route setup for `/viewQuiz` and the api url is `/api/getQuizData`. So when I load `http://localhost:3000/viewQuiz?gpQ=xxxxxx` I want the api to get the correct data. See my codes below

Server.js

```
//Routes
app.get('/startCampaign', function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/start-campaign.html');
});

//Get data
var Quiz = mongoose.model('Quiz', quizSchema);
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

app.get('/api/getQuizData', function(req, res){
    Quiz.find({_id:ObjectId("59b2ac3cfc2283480879025c")}, function(err, quiz) {
      if (err) throw err;

      // object of the user
      res.json(quiz[0]);
    });
});
```

Angular bit..

```
//Get Quiz data
$scope.quizData = '';
$http.get('/api/getQuizData')
.success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  $scope.quizData = data;
})
```

Then I use this AngularJs QuizData binding to display the data. How do I change my server.js file to make it dynamic based on query string value?

Comment: `Quiz.find({_id:ObjectId(req.query.gpQ)}, function(err, quiz) {`

Comment: @Keith this doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: What does `console.log(req.query)` show?

Answer (score 0):

in angular try this 
//req.query consist of GPQ value and that changes dynamically according to what you send after gpq="xyz......"

```
Quiz.findById(req.query.gPQ, function(err, quiz) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // object of the user
  res.json(quiz);
});
```